# Linux console output limits, and long term stability

Tags: linux, command-line, console

A question that has bothered me for some while:

Suppose we have an otherwise non leaky and well made program executed in console, and this program outputs some information periodically.

Will the console be able to receive and show new output essentially indefinitely? Meaning that if I left such a setup on for days, weeks, years even, the console process does not for example slowly eat away all memory, or have something like line count overflow after 2^32 lines?

Answer (score 1):

The console is "simply" another program. That program will use buffers, for output from other programs and to push out to displays or other places.

Those buffers are rarely infinite (in the sense of using all the memory available in the machine address space) but are typically sized to suit the display or can be configured to grow up to however large a user desires.

For a console running on a text-only machine without a mouse or other method to scroll up or down you may not care about buffering more characters than appear on screen. As new lines of data comes in you simply discard old lines. As a result the buffer is a fixed size and probably of the order of kilobytes rather than gigabytes.

For systems which have a graphical display, windowing systems and methods of scrolling around using mouse or other sensible means you can start to look back through data easily. It makes no sense to keep a history of the entire past of the console, especially for long uptime, because as you say it would require some unknowable quantity of RAM.  It could require a few bytes, or it could require an infinite number of bytes. It makes sense then to limit it. Generally this is what every console would do. They would pick a sensible limit as a default and whenever the limit was about to be reached they drop the oldest line in order to free up space.

By setting such a limit they also reduce the console overhead. For the buffer to work you either have to be constantly shuffling things down in the buffer as you delete things, using memory bandwidth to create a new copy each time, or you have a rolling buffer and a pointer to where the next characters get written in it, resetting back to 0 when you reach the end.

They *could* be written to have an infinitely large buffer, but there is no reason to do it that way and many reasons not to. Better to choose a default limit that is "large enough" for most users and let the rest change it if they need to.

There is no stability problem because one console is never likely to use all the address space.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the process goes to the *standard input  (stdin)*  of the *console*.  Note how the words are used: stdin and the console are two distinct things.  The console,  is a process that has a stdin. Whatever comes in here is put into a buffer Which is managed by the console and displayed on the screen. If the buffer runs full, the first lines will be discarded (ring buffer).